# UILabel wrong release into UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, release, uilabel

I have a custom UITableViewCel like this:

```
@synthesize poiNameLabel;
@synthesize poiDistanceLabel;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if ((self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])) {
        // Initialization code
        CGRect nlabelframe = CGRectMake(NAMELABEL_X, NAMELABEL_Y, NAMELABEL_WIDTH, NAMELABEL_HEIGHT);
        UILabel *nlabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:nlabelframe];
        nlabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:NAMELABEL_FONT];
        nlabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        nlabel.minimumFontSize = NAMELABEL_FONT_MIN;
        //nlabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        [self addSubview:nlabel];
        self.poiNameLabel = nlabel;
        [nlabel release];

        CGRect dlabelframe = CGRectMake(DISTANCELABEL_X, DISTANCELABEL_Y, DISTANCELABEL_WIDTH, DISTANCELABEL_HEIGHT);
        UILabel *dlabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:dlabelframe];
        dlabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:DISTANCELABEL_FONT];
        dlabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        dlabel.minimumFontSize = DISTANCELABEL_FONT_MIN;
        dlabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        [self addSubview:dlabel];
        self.poiDistanceLabel = dlabel;
        [dlabel release];

        self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.contentView.opaque = NO;

    }
    return self;
}


- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [poiNameLabel release];
    [poiDistanceLabel release];
}
```

and this is how I fill it:

```
NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[poisSource objectAtIndex:row]];
ResultsViewCell *cell = [[[ResultsViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
cell.poiNameLabel.text = [dic objectForKey:@"name"];
float distance = [[dic objectForKey:@"distance"] floatValue];
NSString *distanceWithUnity;
distance = distance*1000;
if (distance > 1000) {
    distanceWithUnity = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f km", distance/1000];
} else {
    distanceWithUnity = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f mt", distance];
}
cell.poiDistanceLabel.text = distanceWithUnity;
[dic release];
return cell;
```

Everything is ok, but when the UITableCell is deallocated, I get BAD_ACCESS releasing poiDistanceLabel.
I see no problem in my code, no retain errors, so I can't understand what's happening.
The only doubt I have is about how I'm setting the label text: can this be the issue? Why is this happening?

Comment: When you scroll out one of these cells from the list, does it do the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem seems to be in your `dealloc` method:

```
[super dealloc]
```

should be the last call in your `dealloc` method to keep object "alive" while it is deallocating.